# Fourier transform a trig function in Sympy returns unexpected result

Tags: python, sympy, continuous-fourier, symbolic-integration

I think Sympy makes a mistake in calculating the [Fourier transform](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.transforms.fourier_transform) of a trig function. For example:

```
from sympy import fourier_transform, sin
from sympy.abc import x, k
print fourier_transform(sin(x), x, k)
```

The expected answer [via Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier%20transform%20sin%28x%29) is

[image]

but Sympy returns 0. Sometimes the function works very well since `fourier_transform(Heaviside(t)*cos(t),t,omega)` and `fourier_transform(Heaviside(t)*sin(t),t,omega)` return the correct answer. I think Sympy may be using Laplace transform to calculate Fourier transform.

Comment: Well, the Fourier transform of `sin` is a sum of delta functions. It might be the case that Sympy has difficulty representing delta functions. Note also that `sympy.fourier_transform('Heaviside(t)', 't', 'omega')` yields `-I/(2*pi*omega)` for me, whereas in Mathematica, `FourierTransform[HeavisideTheta[t], t, w]` yields `I/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] w) + Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[w]` (so sympy is dropping a delta function here too).

Comment: It is very strange to do so, since sympy does have delta function `DiracDelta`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SymPy computes the Fourier transform by literally computing the integral. I would consider this to be a bug, so feel free to open [an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) for it.

Comment: @kattern You should provide a link to the issue so we can update this based of the status.

Comment: @Hooked Great idea, the link to the issue is <https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2803>.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `noconds=False` to the transform routines to find under which conditions the transformation integral converges. As asmeurer says, we literally compute the defining integral, so you will never see delta functions coming up. In the case of the fourier transform of `cos`, the conditions are a convoluted way of saying "never", which unfortunately sympy does not recognise. (I.e. the algorithm says something like "the integral is zero if blah", and blah never holds.)

For the fourier transform of the step function, the conditions seem to be saying that this works if z has negative argument (angle), not too big. Note that this is indeed when the transform integral converges (b/c you need to pick up a falling exponential term over the positive reals). I don't have time to think about whether the computation is correct in this case.

Comment: I also see the option, but for me I would like `fourier_transform` return `DiracDelta` function instead of a conditioned zero.